# .NET C# WebService call - timeout problem

Tags: c#, .net, timeout

i have a problem, to properly increase timeout call to webservice in .NET framework 4.5. I would like to increase timeout, but whatever I do, I always get timeout exception after 5 minutes.

My call to webservice is formed like this:

```
using (WebService.WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient())
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = wsUsername;
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = wsPassword;

    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        IContextChannel contextChannel = (IContextChannel)client.InnerChannel;
        **contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);**

        var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
        httpRequestProperty.Headers["key"] = apiKey;
        
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
    
        client.WebServiceFunction();
    }
}
```

I already tried different timeout settings, but nothing works..

Setting in app.config, not working:

```
<binding name="WebServiceClient" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
```

Setting on contextChannel, not working:

```
contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
```

Web service is called from winforms application, and whatever I do, i get timeout exception after 5 minutes. Timeout on webservice server is set to 10 minutes, so the problem should be on my (client) side.

What can I do, to increase timeout call to webservice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 5 minutes sounds like a long time for a web service. Are you sure the service itself is working properly and returning data in a timely manner? Sounds to me like you might be trying to tackle the wrong problem

Comment: It is, but i don't have influence on webservice it self.  It's a complicated webservice which in rare examples takes more that 5 minutes. But, this is not the case... The problem is, how to properly increase timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

-> you can set the sendTimeout property of the basicHTTpBinding in client-side code.

-> in my code, SendTimeout of the BasicHttpBinding is set to 15 minutes and binding is applied to the client's endpoint to set timeout for web service call.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;

public class WebServiceHelper
{
    public void CallWebService(string wsUrl, string wsUsername, string wsPassword, string apiKey)
    {
        using (WebService.WebServiceClient client = new WebService.WebServiceClient())
        {
            // Set the credentials for the web service
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = wsUsername;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = wsPassword;

            // Create a binding with the desired timeout
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15) // Adjust timeout value as needed
            };

            // Apply the binding to the client
            client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;

            // Set up the HTTP request properties including authorization and API key
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                // Set the authorization header
                var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
                httpRequestProperty.Headers["key"] = apiKey;

                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

                // Make the web service call
                try
                {
                    client.WebServiceFunction();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException tex)
                {
                    // Handle timeout exception
                    Console.WriteLine($"Timeout exception: {tex.Message}");
                    // You can also rethrow the exception if needed
                    // throw;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle other exceptions
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                    // You can also rethrow the exception if needed
                    // throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Henil, but it's not working either. I'm starting to suspect, that it has to be the problem on the server side. Admin of webservice claims, that server timeout is more that 5 minutes, but I doubt that.
If I try the same code, with my own webservice, timeout works as it should.